# How to fix the responsive design from github page and broken images?

Tags: responsive-design, jekyll, github-pages

I have a portfolio site deployed at github pages and I used jekyll to create it. The issues that I have : 1)The responsive design at mobile it's not right and I also can't see footer, 2) I have broken images that doesn't load i have changed the path several times but still doesn't work i guess I'm out of options?Any suggestions to fix these issues? **My site** : https://lazospap.github.io/LazPap/ **and my repo** : https://github.com/LazosPap/LazPap .

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that the image urls are found, you can tell Jekyll where the image is *before* processing using the `link` tag. Jekyll will track the link of the image before and after processing, so you can rely on your repo's current structure instead of the structure after processing.

```
<img src="{% link images/CSS_3.png %}" class="background-image-right"/>
```

[Docs on link tag](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#link)

Another tip is to create a `.gitignore`, add the following files to the `.gitignore` and then delete them from being tracked by git. You don't need them in your source control.

```
// .gitignore

.jekyll-cache
_site/
```

---

When I run your repo locally and make the browser mobile responsive, the images are not shrinking down. But, I can see your footer. I'm not familiar with the framekworks you're using, though.

Comment: How gitignore works never used it before. I have changed the img src as you showed me and waiting for the cache to clear so i can see the changes

Comment: `.gitignore` is a file that tells git to ignore and not track specific files or folders in the version control. This is useful for temporary or generated things like caches. Jekyll makes a `_site` folder that doesn't need to be tracked. Here's the git documentation on `.gitignore`: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Here's an example `.gitignore` from GitHub for Jekyll: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Jekyll.gitignore

Comment: I followed the answer of JoostS and it worked, I had a mistake at my baseurl thats why I had broken images. But the problem I still have is the responsive design at mobile I have an issue there you can check it.How I'll manage to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `link`, you can also do this:

```
<img src="{{ '/images/CSS_3.png' | prepend: site.baseurl }}" class="background-image-right"/>
```

Comment: How can I fix the responsive design for mobiles cause I don't receive the best responsiveness of my bootstrap theme?